# Python list index out of range when doing inverse BWT

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass blocks of text into an inverse Burrows-Wheeler Transform function from a text file and I'm getting list index out of range errors, not sure why. I'm reading a text file that's had BWT applied to it, breaking it into blocks of size `block_size` and storing them in a list `text`. I then try to call `inverse` on each element in `text`.

```
def inverse(s):
    L = [''] * block_size                                     
    for i in range(block_size):
        L = sorted([s[i] + L[i] for i in range(block_size)])   
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as output_file:
        output_file.write([x for x in L if x.endswith('\0')][0][:-1])

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input_file:
    while block_size:
        block = input_file.read(block_size)
        if not block:
            break
        text.append(block)
    for block in text:
        inverse(block)
```

If I instead pass the entire text file into `inverse` without breaking it up, it works fine; but I want to break my text into manageable chunks. Is it my `text` list that's causing the error?

Comment: `read(n)` does not guarantee you're going to get n bytes back.

Comment: Would that be the cause of the error then? Should I just then use a different method to read X characters?

Comment: You should just make sure that whatever you are passing into `inverse` is actually `block_size` sized.